# Recovering Accidental Storyboard Deletion

Tags: xcode4

I tried looking for the answer but didn't find it.

I accidentally deleted my storyboard in XCode4. Is there anyway that I can retrieve it? I looked in the trash can but there was nothing there.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: Even though I deleted the storyboard, I've noticed that the compiler still compiles and runs the program and has all the same UIButtons and UILabels with the correct sizes, text labels, and positioning. All as if it never was deleted! Im guessing that the information is still there somewhere! does anyone know if there is perhaps a copy saved within xcode somewhere that i can used to recreate the storyboard file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really deleted the file (check in the file system, not just in XCode, see Liam's answer below for the location) and it's not in the trash, there are (afaik) really only two options;

- TimeMachine if you have that running may have a good copy.
- An undelete utility like [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) or [MacKeeper](http://mackeeper.zeobit.com/mac-undelete)

When undeleting, the more you use your disk after deleting a file, the less chance of recovery, so if you're really serious, you should install the program on another Mac and move the disk to that for recovery so that you won't overwrite anything.

Comment: Thanks. I havent used the machine much after it happened. After weighing the choices I have, I think it might be easier to rebuild the storyboard.

Comment: Actually, the weirdest thing just happened, im hoping that I can recover the storyboard since i noticed this: Just out of curiosity, I hit "Run" in XCode and the program compiled and popped up in the simulator as if it was never deleted! Whats going on here?

Answer (score 68):

If it popped up that means you can find it in your project folder. Just look in /projectName/projectName/Base.lproj. The storyboard is there. You can drag it into Xcode and its as good as new.

Comment: This helped me in Xcode 6.1 but I got it in en.lproj

Comment: An awesome solution ;)

Comment: this is a way way better solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can find the Storyboard file in the Base.lproj folder,from there you can just drag it to Xcode

Answer (score 13):

Even if you deleted your main story board, it would be there inside the folder called Base.lProj
*(This folder will be in the folder where your source and header files lie in the normal case.)*

So go to Xcode. Right click in the Project navigator in the left side tab and add these files to the project again.

Answer (score 9):

I have done the same thing. Open up your Trash on the desktop and drag the storyboard back into the open Xcode file.

Comment: I've done that but it has not moved to back to Base.Iproj. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 8):

Try right clicking on the Project folder and then proceed to `Add Files to yourprojectname` > `Base.Iproj` > `yourstoryboard file` and add this back.

Answer (score 2):

I just did the same. It was pretty easy to recover if you were using git (and there was not much change from the last commit).

All you have to do is to restore your project.pbxproj file.
Try git diff your .xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Once you confirm that restoring that file will save your storyboard (since you will find deleted lines around MainStoryboard), run this simple command:

```
git checkout project.pbxproj
```

If you made some change to the project (like adding files) since the last commit, you will find some added lines as well. Save them by running git diff before above command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I localized my storyboard and and failed at checking the wright option that leaded to only one storyboard.string file and my original storyboard was deleted by xcode. Hopefully, the original storyboard file was put un the trash so I was able to restore it. Perhaps now the new XCode 8 version puts the file int the trash by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you have committed before that happened, you can go old commit and copy storyboard's source code, and then you can create new storyboard and paste this code on it.