# Xcode 5: Deleted Main Storyboard

Tags: xcode

I accidentally deleted the main story board off Xcode 5 and i can't find the file anywhere  its not in the trash and is not on the system at all is there any way too  get it back or even just to create a new story board thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why I always create a local git repo, even for personal projects that won't go in a remote repo ever. Go to File -> New -> File..., choose User Interface, then choose Storyboard. That will give you a new one.

Comment: Find /projectName/projectName/Base.lproj http://stackoverflow.com/a/11348365/353438

Answer (score 2):

Go to File -> New -> File..., choose "User Interface", then choose "Storyboard". That will give you a new one.

As I mentioned in my comment, you probably should create a local git repository when you create new projects. The option is right there when you're creating the new project. Then you can do periodic commits as well so that even without a remote repo, you still have version control, and some degree of safety from accidentally deleting files.

EDIT:

To choose the new storyboard, choose your project on the lefthand side in Xcode, make sure your target is selected, choose the "General" tab, and make sure your storyboard is selected under "Main Interface".

Comment: thanks for the advice yeah ill keep that in mind for the future cheers for your help !

Comment: thanks for the help it worked i may seem really  daft but my IOS simulator is not running the old story board  any ideas on how to refresh it or link it too the new one  ? ( I've already linked all my IB outlets etc)

Comment: @GJH385 I added more to my answer to help with that problem as well.