# I accidentally deleted View Controller

Tags: ios, view, uiview, controller

I accidentally deleted View Controller in Main.Storyboard and now I am trying to build and run my game and it says build "Sussess" but it builds Lanch Image Appears and then the screen is white and nothing happens please help me. My game is in appStore already I cant remake it!!!! What should I do?

I have this in debug area!

```
2014-09-15 02:51:02.680 Greenchick[4300:60b] -[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb599f50
2014-09-15 02:51:02.692 Greenchick[4300:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb599f50'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: have a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087115/recovering-accidental-storyboard-deletion

Comment: Restore from version control, which you are using, right?

Comment: How do I restore from version control? And what do you mean right?

Comment: If you haven't set up version control then restore from backup.  If you don't have a backup, start typing

Comment: It is not typing it is squared view controller I accidentally deleted it and then I placed new one from object library. I can start type the hole game again - it is in appStore already. There will be al lot of typing to do to create same new game

Answer (score 0):

I think usually, the file gets deleted from the project but is usually present in the project folder. Check if your view controller is present in the Project folder. If it is present, you can add to your project again.

Comment: Sushrut hi! Where is project folder located?

Comment: Click on any file and then on its properties. You will find a property named "Full Path". It shows the location of that file.

Comment: OK I resolved that problem! I turnes out that I needed: place another View Controller (which was UIView Controller) and click on border of UIView Controller which highlights it in  blue then in "Identity Inspector" change "Castom Class" to its original class before you deleted VC, main was View Controller. After that click onthe center of View Controller and in identity inspector change castom class to Its original type of view Mine was SKView because my app was game and that is it. I almost started to making my game over and I would had to do so many things.