# What to do if you accidentally remove the reference to a file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

In the middle of coding an app, I wanted to delete a button. What I did not realize was that I was actually selected `main.storyboard`. When I pressed backspace to delete `main.storyboard` I pressed "Remove reference". At this point I tried command + z, but ,unfortunately, `main.storyboard` did not come back.I tried to run the app but I kept getting signal `SIGABRT`.

My question here is if you accidentally remove the reference to a file is there any way of recovering it?

Comment: You don't use version control, do you?

Comment: No, but i plan to in the future

Comment: It should go in your trash. Drag it from your trash back into your proj.

Comment: It is not in my trash for some reason

Comment: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087115/recovering-accidental-storyboard-deletion
Please check the answer here.

Comment: I pressed remove reference, sorry for the mistake

Comment: And I keep getting the SIGABRT error

Comment: That means, that you should find your main.storyboard in the file system folder of your project. Just drag'n'drop it into you xcode-project and you should be fine.

Comment: You maybe should use a CV like Git.

Comment: Guys, I just want to know what is wrong with this question so that in the future I can improve my questions

Comment: @tj75467 Your question (in it's current form) is perfectly fine. Looking at the edit history the only problem was confusing "Move to trash" with "Remove reference", since they require a different answer. Don't be discouraged by the downvotes. I just made the same silly mistake and your question and answer helped me alot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only "Remove reference", the file is disappearing only from Xcode and remaining in your real folder. Try to add Main.storyboard again from Xcode file navigator like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have accidentally removed the reference of a file in your Xcode project (such as main.storyboard or app.delegate) go find the file you removed the reference of in finder. Then drag and drop the file into where all of your files are located in xcode (on the left).

Similarly, if you have trash a file, go into your trash and just drag and drop the project back into xcode.

Hopefully this helps